# Unable to scroll -

Tags: php, html, css

Simply trying to get my page to scroll, simply added 'br' to test. This can be  seen in the file below -

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    header("location: login.php");
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Menu Flexbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-hQpvDQiCJaD2H465dQfA717v7lu5qHWtDbWNPvaTJ0ID5xnPUlVXnKzq7b8YUkbN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style6.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/icons/favicon.png" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:400,300,600,500,700&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style9.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="table" id="main">
            <div class="table-cell">
                <div class="menu">
                    <div class="menu-item"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span>Home</span></div>
                    <div class="menu-item"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i><span>Panel</span></div>
                    <div class="menu-item"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><span>Profile</span></div>
                    <div class="menu-item"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span>Support</span></div>
                    <a class="menu-item" href="index.php?logout='1'"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i><span>Logout</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
<a target="_blank" style="display: block; position: fixed; bottom: 45px; right: 10px; width: 200px;" href=""><img src="https://i.imgur.com/EV5CGy2.png" alt="logo"/></a>
<a target="_blank" style="display: block; position: fixed; bottom: 15px; right: -24px; width: 200px;" href="http://www.abr.business.gov.au/ABN/View/93742390655"><img src="" alt=""/>ABN: 93 742 390 655</a>
</div>

    <div id="wrap1">
                    <div class="ml-auto pt-5">
                <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
                    Welcome, <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong>.
                <?php endif ?>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div id="wrap">
                <br><br><br><h1 style="font-weight: 300; padding-left: 80px">Shopping cart -</h1>
                <p style="font-weight: 300; padding-left: 80px ">Check out with your items</p>
                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                example
                <br>
                example
                <br>
                example
                <br>
            </div>


</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
(function(){
var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/5b7d1d95afc2c34e96e7ca57/default';
s1.charset='UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
})();
</script>

<?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) : ?>
<div class="error success" >
<h3>
<?php
echo $_SESSION['success'];
unset($_SESSION['success']);
?>
</h3>
</div>
<?php endif ?>

</script>

</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibNIY.png)

I simply can not scroll down -

Please ensure you let me know if you need anything other than what has been provied

CSS -

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#main{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ddeaf1; 
}
.table{
  display: table;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.table-cell{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu{
  background-color: white;
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #c0c0c0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #c0c0c0;
  -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #c0c0c0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #c0c0c0;
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#c0c0c0, Direction=NaN, Strength=5);
}

@media all and (max-width: 900px){
  .menu{
    width: 80%;
  }
}

.menu-item{
  font-size: 17px;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 25px;
  transition: all .2s;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #636363;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-item > span{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: white;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #226eab;
  padding: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .2s .1s;
  transform: translateY(70px);
  z-index: -1;
}

.menu-item:hover{
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #c0c0c0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #c0c0c0;
  -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #c0c0c0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #c0c0c0;
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#c0c0c0, Direction=NaN, Strength=5);
  flex: 2;
  color: #226eab;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index: 3;
}

.menu-item:hover > span{
  transform: translateY(35px);
  opacity: 1;
}

#wrap{
     width: 95%;
     min-width: 900px;
     margin-left: 18%;
}

#wrap1{
     width: 95%;
     min-width: 900px;
     margin-left: 80%;

}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, this is my first project so don't judge to hard :)

Comment: Please add related code

Comment: Updated it my friend :)

Comment: I do not thing this has anything to do with php part. Try to write minimal html code which does NOT work and post it here.

Comment: Understood. Please just ignore it for now.

Comment: All documents are updated, please check again.

Comment: Hello, I appreciated your response. I do not understand it fully however. If you could please elaborate... oh you deleted your message :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove  `overflow: hidden;` from your CSS body element. If you do not want to let page elements cause your page to be wider than the actual viewport’s width, replace it with `max-width: 100vw;` and `overflow-x: hidden;`. `vw` is the unit for a percentage of the viewport width.

Answer (score 0):

You have added

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the body, so you can't scroll. Please remove the `hidden` so that you can scroll

Answer (score 0):

1. please check you have enough data (> your view port) for scrollbar to appear.
2. Please refer here for css changes if needed
   [enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp)
[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp)

3. Try css on body
   overflow-y: scroll;

*remove overflow:hidden on body